# How can I limit motion blur to a specific object?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, motion-blur

I have a plane with propeller. The plane is moving and so is the propeller but I just want the propeller to have motion blur and not the plane body. How can I achieve the effect? I am using blender render engine.

Here is my image currently:

[image: my plane]

Comment: Not sure this is an answer, but it would work: Render the prop separately in BI with Alpha: Transparent, creating a movie of the prop motion alone. In VSE, composite this alpha movie in over your aircraft.... So you would have a full render range of the propeller being transparent, and the same full range of the aircraft less the propeller without motion blur, then combine them in VSE.